# Using app style inside android module

Tags: android, android-styles, datepickerdialog, android-module

I've got a module with some custom components. Inside one of these I have a DatePickerDialog. I need to using a custom accent color for these. How can I retrieve the color from the main app style? Is there a way to use the same style avoiding circular reference?
Otherwise, there is a method to set programmatically the accent color for a DatePickerDialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a style at your sub module and define it with the **same name** at your main module. App will override sub module's style and apply it from your main module.